# ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python coding, I am getting this error when i try to run my python script, can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?
I am trying to make a maths competition program, it should first ask for both player's names, then continue on to give each player a question until both players have answered 10 questions each. After that, it should show the score each player has got, and tell them who the winner is.

```
 ## Maths Competition ##
import sys
import time
import random
p1_score = 0
p2_score = 0
main_loop = 'y'
loop = 'y'
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    print('Welcome Mac user')
elif sys.plaform == 'win32' or 'win64':
    print('Welcome Windows user')
else:
    print('Welcome Linux user')
time.sleep(2)
print('This is a two player maths competition game, Player 1, please enter your name.')
p1_name = input()
print('now player 2 please..')
p2_name = input()
print('Processing...')
time.sleep(2)
print(p1_name+''' will first be given a random maths question,
they then have to answer that question or just press enter if they can't get it.
Then '''+ p2_name +''' will be given a question and they have to do the same thing. Each
time a player gets an answer correct, 10 points are automatically added to their score.
Each player will be given 10 questions in total, in the end, the one with the most right
answers will win. If it is a draw, a penalty round will happen, enjoy
Ps. '**' means 'to the power off'. ''')
time.sleep(5)
while main_loop == 'y':
    num_of_tries = 0
    while loop == 'y':
     num_of_tries = num_of_tries + 1
     if num_of_tries >20:
         break
     ops = ['x','/','+','-','**']
     num1 = random.randrange(100)
     num2 = random.randrange(35)
     sel_op = random.choice(ops)
     print(p1_name+', please press enter once you are ready to get your question')
     input()
     if sel_op == 'x':
         ans = num1 * num2
     elif sel_op == '/':
         ans = num1 / num2
     elif sel_op == '+':
         ans = num1 + num2
     elif sel_op == '-':
         ans = num1 - num2
     elif sel_op == '**':
         ans = num1 ** num2
     p1_ans = input('Your question is: %d %s %d' % (num1,sel_op,num2))
     if p1_ans == ans:
         p1_score = p1_score + 10
     num1 = random.randrange(100)
     num2 = random.randrange(35)
     sel_op = random.choice(ops)
     print(p2_name+', please press enter once you are ready to get your question')
     input()
     if sel_op == 'x':
         ans2 = num1 * num2
     elif sel_op == '/':
         ans2 = num1 / num2
     elif sel_op == '+':
         ans2 = num1 + num2
     elif sel_op == '-':
         ans2 = num1 - num2
     elif sel_op == '**':
         ans2 = num1 ** num2
     p2_ans = input('Your question is: %d %s %d' % (num1,sel_op,num2))
     if p2_ans == ans2:
         p2_score = p2_score + 10
    print(p1_name+' got %d' % (p1_score))
    print(p2_name+' got %d' % (p2_score))
    if p1_score > p2_score:
         print(p1_name+' is the WINNER!')
    elif p2_score > p1_score:
         print(p2_name+' is the WINNER!')
    print('Would you like to play another? y/n')
    repeat = input()
    if any ( [repeat == 'y', repeat == 'Y'] ):
         print('Sure thing, wait a couple of seconds for me to set things up again...')
         time.sleep(3)
    elif any ( [repeat == 'n', repeat == 'N'] ):
         break
    else:
         print('I\'ll take that as a NO')
         time.sleep(2)
         break
```

Comment: What is the problem when you run your code? any error or wrong answer?!

Answer (score 4):

```
 num2 = random.randrange(35)
```

can give you zero and will lead to a division by zero in this line:

```
 ans2 = num1 / num2
```

you probably want something like:

```
 random.randrange(start = 1, stop = 35 + 1)
```

which will generate numbers between 1 and 35 (both inclusive).

---

A side remark: unless you want the user to enter floating point numbers such as 0.8333333333333334 (which is very likely NOT to be exactly equal to the value calculated in your program) for division (assuming you are using python3), it is better to throw a value for the result and for the divisor and then calculate the dividend from it.

Answer (score 0):

Andre Holzner is correct. Here is some Examples of basic usage:

`>>> random.random()        # Random float x, 0.0 <= x < 1.0
0.37444887175646646`

`>>> random.uniform(1, 10)  # Random float x, 1.0 <= x < 10.0
1.1800146073117523`

`>>> random.randint(1, 10)  # Integer from 1 to 10, endpoints included
7`

`>>> random.randrange(0, 101, 2)  # Even integer from 0 to 100
26`

`>>> random.choice('abcdefghij')  # Choose a random element
'c'`

```
>>> items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> random.shuffle(items)
>>> items
[7, 3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 1]
```

`>>> random.sample([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],  3)  # Choose 3 elements
[4, 1, 5]`

**To learn more about random here is the** [Link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)